# JavaScript "if" and "else" error

Tags: jquery

What's wrong with this code am I missing something? :( I think the problem is at if and else..

```
$(function () {
    if ($("a#toggle_sidebar").length > 0) {
        $('#toggle_sidebar').click(function () {
            $('#dw_right').show();
            $('#content-container div#container').css('width', '83%');
        });
    } else {
        $('#toggle_sidebar').click(function () {
            $('#dw_right').hide();
            $('#content-container div#container').css('width', '100%');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You should tell us what is not working for you?

Comment: We need to know: 1) What the actual problem you're seeing is 2) a short, self contained, complete example that reproduces the problem, 3) what you expect the output to be. (Hint: You should be including the HTML as well)

Comment: I’m voting to reopen it, as I have an actual idea what to post as an answer. And I definitely agree with closing it too quickly. There is no harm in keeping a question open when there is still hope that the user can reply to the comments and fix the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the click event for showing or hiding would only be handled once, but not reversed. If you add an if/else in the click handler you can then easily toggle the element. The document ready will only be run once.

```
$(function () {
    if ($("a#toggle_sidebar").length > 0) {
        $('#toggle_sidebar').click(function () {
            if(!$(this).is(':visible'))
            {
                $('#dw_right').show();
                $('#content-container div#container').css('width', '83%');
            }
            else
            {  
                $('#dw_right').hide();
                $('#content-container div#container').css('width', '100%');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Despite me announcing my answer, you were actually quicker than me. So take this +1 ;)